# Why SIMPLE XML addChild() adds 3 childs?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am developing simple class for loging errors to xml file.

What I expect is root element log with 3 child elemens error with child element message.
But output is Message 1Message 2Message 3 Message 1Message 2Message 3 Message 1Message 2Message 3
Everything is here 3 times. do you have any idea why and how to rewrite the code?

I got test.php with following code:

```
<?php

    require_once '../meenee/system/Logger.class.php';

    $logger = new Logger;
    $logger->logErrMessage("Message 1");
    $logger->logErrMessage("Message 2");
    $logger->logErrMessage("Message 3");
    $logger->showErrLog();
```

log.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>

</log>
```

Logger.class.php

```
class Logger{

public $errFile;
public $errXMLLog;

public function __construct(){

    $this->errFile = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../error/log.xml";

    if(!file_exists($this->errFile)){
        throw new WarningException("File does not exists. ".$this->errFile);
    }

    if(!($this->errXMLLog = simplexml_load_file($this->errFile))){
        throw new WarningException("Can't simple xml load file. ".$this->errFile);
    }

}

    public function logErrMessage($message){        

        $count = $this->errXMLLog->count();
        $this->errXMLLog->addChild('error');
        $this->errXMLLog->error[$count]->addChild('message', $message);

        $this->errXMLLog->asXml($this->errFile);

    }

    public function showErrLog(){
        foreach ($this->errXMLLog->children() as $child){
            echo file_get_contents($this->errFile);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `showErrLog` proc:

For each child (there are 3 children) 
do 
echo file contents (entire file contents, where file contains 3 messages.).

-> You echo file contents 3 times.

N.B. Probably you need to add EOL char to separate rows in the files.

Comment: Ou.. there was something else in foreach before. Thank you very much for help.